# Examine whether $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $C[0, 1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Examine whether $\| \cdot \|$ is a norm on $C[0, 1]$, where $\|x\| = \min \{  \|x\| _{\infty}, 2\|x\|_{1}\}$ for all $x \in C[0, 1]$.

Comment: How far have you come with this exercise? Do you know what conditions you need to check?

Comment: I think triangle inequality not hold.

Comment: Can you find an example where it doesn't hold?

Comment: No, I can't , please help@md2perpe

Comment: Please help, by providing the function $f$ and $g.$

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly asserted, the triangle inequality does not hold.

Take $f \equiv 1$, and $g : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as:

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
5 - \frac{25}3 x &: \text{ if } x \in \left[0, \frac35\right]\\
0 &: \text{ if } x \in \left[\frac35, 1\right]
\end{cases}$$

$g$ is affine between $(0, 5)$ and $\left(\frac35, 0\right)$ and zero afterwards. $f$ and $g$ are obviosly continuous.

You can check that $\|f\|_\infty = \|f\|_1 = 1$ and $\|g\|_\infty = 5$, $\|g\|_1 = \frac32$.

Also, we have $\|f + g\|_\infty = 6$ and $\|f + g\|_1 = \frac52$.

So,
$$\|f + g\| = \min\{\|f + g\|_\infty, 2\|f + g\|_1\} = \min\{6, 5\} = 5$$
but
$$\|f\| + \|g\| = \min\{\|f\|_\infty, 2\|f\|_1\} + \min\{\|g\|_\infty, 2\|g\|_1\} = \min\{1, 2\} + \min\{5, 3\} = 4$$

Hence, $\|\cdot\|$ is not a norm on $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Is there any general way for finding the function $g.$

Comment: @1256 If we try to prove the triangle inequality we have:
$$\|x+y\| = \min \{  \|x+y\| _{\infty}, 2\|x+y\|_{1}\} \le \min \{  \|x\|_\infty+\|y\| _\infty, 2\|x\|_1+2\|y\|_{1}\}$$

Now we cannot conclude that this is $\le \min\{\|x\|_\infty, 2\|x\|_1\}+\min\{\|y\|_\infty, 2\|y\|_1\}$. This is because the inequality

$$\min \{  a+b, c + d\} \le \min\{a, c\}+\min\{b, d\}$$

is not true in general (for $a, b, c, d \ge 0$). For example

$$\min \{  1+5, 2 + 3\} \not\le \min\{1, 2\}+\min\{5, 3\}$$

Comment: Now just try to find continuous functions $f, g$ such that $\|f\|_\infty = \|f\|_1 = 1$ and $\|g\|_\infty = 5$, $\|g\|_1 = \frac32$. You also want that $\|f + g\|_\infty = \|f\|_\infty + \|g\|_\infty$ and $\|f + g\|_1= \|f\|_1+ \|g\|_1$ so it is sufficient that $f, g$ are nonnegative and attain their maxima for same $x \in [0,1]$.